# Passing external attribute or Input in an Angular Custom Element

Tags: angular, typescript, video.js, custom-component, custom-element

I am trying to pass an object input in an angular custom element tag. The custom element consists of a videojs tag. Element is not reading the input that I am giving in the custom element tag.

This code here is my Video player component that I want to convert into a custom element.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, On Destroy, OnInit, ViewChild,AfterViewInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import videojs from "video.js"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-player',
  templateUrl: './my-video-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-video-player.component.scss'],
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class MyVideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy,AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('myVideoPlayer',{static:true})
  myVideoPlayer:ElementRef


  @Input() options:{
    fluid:boolean,
    aspectRatio:string,
    autoplay:boolean,
    controls:boolean,
    // height:number,
    // width:number,
    sources:{
      src:string,
      type:string
    }[],
  }

  player:videojs.Player;

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.player = videojs(this.myVideoPlayer.nativeElement, this.options, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log('onPlayerReady', this);
    });    
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    
  }

}
```

Here is the HTML for the video player component

```
<video id="video-js" preload="none" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls #myVideoPlayer></video>
```

Here is the appModule code where I have converted the MyVideoPlayerComponent into a custom element.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, DoBootstrap, Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyVideoPlayerComponent } from './my-video-player/my-video-player.component';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyVideoPlayerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents:[MyVideoPlayerComponent]
})

export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private injector:Injector){

    const webComponent=createCustomElement(MyVideoPlayerComponent,{injector:this.injector});
    
    customElements.define('custom-player',webComponent)

  }

  

  ngDoBootstrap(){}
 }
```

After building the project, or even if I am directly using the  inside a testing component that I have made in the same angular project. Its showing the video player component but not playing the video as it cannot read the source even when I am providing the attributes.

The code shown below as to how I am trying to give the input to the custom element.

```
<custom-player options="{ autoplay: true, controls: true, sources: [{ src: '../../assets/video.mp4', type: 'video/mp4' }]}" ></custom-player>
```

Will be greatful if you look into this problem.

Here is the given screen shot of the custom element that I am declaring.

The Red mark shows that it is picking up the src, while the highlighted marker shows that it is not putting the src inside the video tag.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cueh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need `../../` when starting from assets (thats usually a valid starting point from the configs).

Also, you want to change `<custom-player options=` to `<custom-player [options]=` (without the [] you actually pass in a string, not an object).

I suppose you followed some tutorial like [this](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-angular.html). If the above has no effect, try comparing to that example to see if there are other relevant differences.

**Edit:**
A very simple example on property binding:

```
// interface for options

export interface VideoOptions {
  fluid?: boolean;
  aspectRation?: string;
  autoplay?: boolean;
  controls?: boolean;
  sources?: Sources[];
}

export interface Source {
  src: string;
  type: string;
}

// ParentComponent ts

export class ParentComponent {
  options: VideoOptions = {
    autoplay: true, 
    controls: true, 
    sources: [{ src: 'assets/video.mp4', type: 'video/mp4' }]
  }
}

// ParentComponent html

<app-child-component [options]="options">
</app-child-component>

// ChildComponent ts
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() options: VideoOptions;
}

// ChildComponent html
<div>
  {{options?.fluid}} <br>
  {{options?.aspectRatio}} <br>
  {{options?.controls}} <br>
  {{options?.autoplay}} <br>
  <ng-container *ngIf="options.sources">
    <div *ngFor="let source of options.sources">
      {{source.src}} --- {{source.type}}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: this is actually a `<custom-player>` is basically a custom web component. Is my method of making the component correct? And I have read in some places that in a custom component you dont have to use [].

Comment: `[prop]='someVal'` (property-binding) is a general mechanism of angular for binding a value to a property in a component referenced in the template. I'd recommend you move the whole options-object from the html to a variable in the ts file and pass that into your component btw. (html should be kept as clean as possible). Aside from that, this mechanism has nothing to do with whether you use your own or some imported/native component. The link I've added does actually exactly what you do (with a custom player component wrapping the video tag) and uses [].

Comment: Okay now. I have found the reason why my custom video player was not actually getting the source for the video and also the rest of the controls. I am using Videojs in angular inside the custom component. VideoJs accepts an Object as options

`
<app-my-video-player [options]="{ autoplay: true, controls: true, sources: [{ src: '../../assets/video.mp4', type: 'video/mp4' }]}"></app-my-video-player>

`

Like this above. But when I am passing the same object through the custom component attributes, its converting it into a string rather then an object .

Comment: `<custom-player my-source="{autoplay: true, controls: false, sources: [{ src: './video.mp4', type: 'video/mp4' }]}"></custom-player>`

here is my custom component where the my-source attribute should be sent as an object, but its going in as a string, due to which the videojs player is not reading it properly.

Comment: Solved. I just needed to convert the string. First I converted the string using JSON.Stringfy. Then I converted it back into JSON.parse twice and hence I got the desired result. Altho it wasnt a very conventional method and I am sure people can have better solutions. But for the time being it worked for me. Thank you :)

Comment: It sends in the string because you are not using `[]` on your custom component. That has to be `<custom-player [my-source]=...` (the property was `options` in your initial post). That is exactly what I wrote. You don't need to to any extra converting/parsing.

Comment: I have tried adding the `[]` to the custom component like `[my-source]` but it is not even reading it. And from what I have read in articles, the custom component actually takes the input without the []. Atleast thats the case in angular. After we have built the custom component, for example, if we are taking input like 

`@Input() mySource:object` 

Then we have to use this input like my-source when giving an input through the custom element in angular. Altho I am sure you are right when talking about a simple angular element we do use `[]` but do not use it with a custom web component.

Comment: `Property binding` has **nothing** to do with custom component or not. That is a standard angular mechanism and works so long the element has the respective property (either a standard property or one defined in a custom component). Please have a read on the docs https://angular.io/guide/property-binding If you couldn't get it to work with your setup, there is something else wrong. I added a small example for property binding to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already worked it out from your comments, but just to make it clear for anyone else who ends up here with the same problem, this is why this happens.

When you convert the component to an Angular web component, any inputs will be mapped as described here:

https://angular.io/guide/elements#mapping

> A custom element hosts an Angular component, providing a bridge between the data and logic defined in the component and standard DOM APIs. Component properties and logic maps directly into HTML attributes and the browser's event system.

> The creation API parses the component looking for input properties, and defines corresponding attributes for the custom element. It transforms the property names to make them compatible with custom elements, which do not recognize case distinctions. The resulting attribute names use dash-separated lowercase. For example, for a component with @Input('myInputProp') inputProp, the corresponding custom element defines an attribute my-input-prop.

The custom element just hosts Angular, it's not an Angular component itself. To pass data to the input, you have to use the attribute that Angular creates on that element, similar to how you'd use a data attribute. The attribute value is a string, so you have to convert it to and from JSON if you want to pass in an object.